# USB Device Enumeration on OS X

Tags: macos, usb, driver, kernel-extension

I have a codeless kext that I use to connect to a USB single-chip device (CSR BC4) - it works great. If I connect multiple devices to an external hub, it still works great.

In the IOKitPersonalities dictionary of my info.plist, for the device and interface dictionaries, I have been matching on the CSR driver in the IOBluetoothFamily.kext with a CFBundleIdentifier that referenced that CSR kext and the IOClass from that package.

Fast forward to a new device that uses multiple CSR BC7 chips on an internal hub. Long story short, I was unable to get that device to properly match all the chips in the device. An Apple driver would generally grab two of the chips. If I plugged in two devices, I would get all the chips from one and no chips from the other. Days of digging ensued. I kept seeing references on Apple lists about using a CFBundleIdentifier of "com.apple.kernel.iokit" or "com.apple.kpi.iokit" with an IOClass of "IOService"

I tried com.apple.kernel.iokit with no luck for neither of my devices. Since I am on a 64-bit platform, I decided to try com.apple.kpi.iokit - bingo! Both devices work like a charm.

My question is what am I really matching to? I can understand matching the device to an existing driver, but what am I matching to in this case? I cannot find anything definitive from Apple that really tells me what I am doing.

Any help appreciated!

Example initial personality:

```
MyCsrDevice  
  CFBundleIdentifier    com.apple.driver.CSRUSBBluetoothHCIController  
  IOClass               CSRUSBBluetoothHCIController  
  IOProviderClass       IOUSBDevice  
  idProduct             32  
  idVendor              vvvv  

MyCsrInterface  
  CFBundleIdentifier    com.apple.driver.CSRUSBBluetoothHCIController  
  IOClass               CSRUSBBluetoothHCIController  
  IOProviderClass       IOUSBInterface  
  idProduct             32  
  idVendor              vvvv 
  bInterfaceNumber      0  
  bConfigurationValue   1
```

Example current personality:

```
MyCsrDevice  
  CFBundleIdentifier    com.apple.kpi.iokit  
  IOClass               IOService  
  IOProviderClass       IOUSBDevice  
  idProduct             32  
  idVendor              vvvv 

MyCsrInterface  
  CFBundleIdentifier    com.apple.kpi.iokit  
  IOClass               IOService  
  IOProviderClass       IOUSBInterface  
  idProduct             32  
  idVendor              vvvv 
  bInterfaceNumber      0  
  bConfigurationValue   1
```

Comment: It's not quite clear to me what your final personality/personalities that you're asking about look like. Also, what were they before?

Comment: Added before/after personality entries. I am pretty sure the driver matching in the original personalities is OK for the chip itself because as noted, I can get a match on one chip with one device plugged in, and all chips of a second device if two devices are plugged in. There is either something I am missing (likely), or something odd (to me) going on that allows the system to preemptively match to the chips before my kext.